# Error in preparedstatement.executeupdate()

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I was executing my code on IntelliJ and it shows an error in this code, I don't understand why? I just have 3 columns and 1 row in my database and I want to update each column with new values( VARCHAR() ), but keeps showing this error.

```java
print("\n>>");//print is a function which does System.out.print("");
String url= in.escinput();//escinput() is a function which does ob.nextLine()
print(">>");
String user=in.escinput();
print(">>");
String pass=in.escinput();
String nurl="",nuser="",npass="";
println("Uploading updates...");
try {
    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    Statement s=c.createStatement();
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ps=c.prepareStatement("Update conn set url="+url);
    ps=c.prepareStatement("Update conn set user="+user);
    ps=c.prepareStatement("Update conn set password="+pass);
    ps.executeUpdate();
    ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery("SELECT * from conn");
    while (rs.next())
    {
        nurl=(rs.getString("url"));
        nuser=(rs.getString("user"));
        npass=(rs.getString("password"));
    }
    if ((nurl.equals(url))||(nuser.equals(user))||(npass.equals(pass)))
    {
        if ((nurl.equals(url))&&(nuser.equals(user))&&(npass.equals(pass)))
            println("Update was sucessful");
        else
        {
            if (!(nurl.equals(url)))
                println("URL was not updated");
            if (!(nuser.equals(user)))
                println("USER was not updated");
            if (!(npass.equals(pass)))
                println("PASSWORD was not updated");
        }
    }
    c.close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    in.conerror();
    String h=in.escinput();
    if (h.equals("printST"))
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In this line

```java
PreparedStatement ps;
ps=c.prepareStatement("Update conn set url="+url);
ps=c.prepareStatement("Update conn set user="+user);
ps=c.prepareStatement("Update conn set password="+pass);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

IntelliJ shows this error

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'passs' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1350)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025)
    at JA_2_0.main(JA_2_0.java:256)
```

I don't understand what's happening, please help

Comment: What you are doing has nothing to do with prepared statements

Comment: Bro the `at JA_2_0.main(JA_2_0.java:256)` the line number 256 is ps.executeUpdate();

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Please do not concatenate values into a query string. Use parameter placeholders (`?`) and set the parameter values using the `setXXX` methods before executing. Also, you're leaking statement handles by preparing three statements in a row, only executing the third one. All JDBC resources like connection, statements, and result sets need to be closed to prevent resource leaks. I recommend reading up on try-with-resources.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don’t see `passs` (with three `s` characters) in your code, I’m guessing the `pass` variable contains something like `,passs` in it, quite possibly as a deliberate measure to test your proper use of PreparedStatement.

### Don’t invent your own sanitizing of input

I assume `in.escinput()` is meant to sanitize a string so it’s safe to place into an SQL statement.  However, no programmer should be doing that themselves.  PreparedStatement already does that, and it will always do it better than any application programmer can:

```
String pass = ob.nextLine();

// ...

ps = c.prepareStatement("Update conn set password=?");
ps.setString(1, pass);
```

### Repeated assignments are destructive, not additive

The assignment operator (`=`) does not add to a variable.  When you assign three values to `ps`, you are just replacing the value of `ps`.  The old value is discarded.  There is no secret mechanism remembering or adding the assignments into a batch operation.

You probably just want a single update statement:

```
String url = ob.nextLine();
String user = ob.nextLine();
String pass = ob.nextLine();

// ...

ps = c.prepareStatement("Update conn set url=?, user=?, password=?");
ps.setString(1, url);
ps.setString(2, user);
ps.setString(3, pass);
ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close();
```

You could also do it as three statements, though that doesn’t have any benefit, and in fact would be slower:

```
ps = c.prepareStatement("Update conn set url=?");
ps.setString(1, url);
ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close();
ps = c.prepareStatement("Update conn set user=?");
ps.setString(1, user);
ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close();
ps = c.prepareStatement("Update conn set password=?");
ps.setString(1, pass);
ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close();
```

### Method calls don’t need to be encased in parentheses

Finally, you don’t need parentheses around every expression.  Generally, parentheses are only needed when you need to override the natural precedence of operators.  While they don’t make a difference in how the program behaves, they do make your code harder to read and harder to maintain.

Meaning, you can change this:

```
nurl=(rs.getString("url"));
nuser=(rs.getString("user"));
npass=(rs.getString("password"));
```

to this:

```
nurl=rs.getString("url");
nuser=rs.getString("user");
npass=rs.getString("password");
```

And you can change this:

```
if ((nurl.equals(url))||(nuser.equals(user))||(npass.equals(pass)))
{
    if ((nurl.equals(url))&&(nuser.equals(user))&&(npass.equals(pass)))
```

to this:

```
if (nurl.equals(url) || nuser.equals(user) || npass.equals(pass))
{
    if (nurl.equals(url) && nuser.equals(user) && npass.equals(pass))
```

And you can change this:

```
if (!(nurl.equals(url)))
    println("URL was not updated");
if (!(nuser.equals(user)))
    println("USER was not updated");
if (!(npass.equals(pass)))
    println("PASSWORD was not updated");
```

to this:

```
if (!nurl.equals(url))
    println("URL was not updated");
if (!nuser.equals(user))
    println("USER was not updated");
if (!npass.equals(pass))
    println("PASSWORD was not updated");
```

The period (`.`) has extremely high precedence, so an expression that uses it is treated as a single value in almost every circumstance.